# Integrate jenkins with AWS server

Tags: devops

Jenkins is installed on  local server and gradle & npm build tools are installed on aws server , so i want to connect jenkins to aws server to build a backend job and frontend using pieline so please help me ..

Devops Issue , jenkins pipeline

Comment: Apart from being off-topic, see: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-jenkins-on-AWS/

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: *You have admin access rights on AWS Server and Jenkins Local.*

If you are using jenkins pipeline then you will want to have AWS EC2 instance as a node.

As a jenkins admin, you can manage jenkins and go to nodes and setup a node which will use AWS EC2 server with npm as aa node. Read following documentation on Node setup.
[https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/#:~:text=Nodes%20are%20the%20%22machines%22%20on,go%20outside%20the%20configured%20threshold](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/#:%7E:text=Nodes%20are%20the%20%22machines%22%20on,go%20outside%20the%20configured%20threshold).

Once you have communication between Jenkins Local and AWS EC2 Server using Node.
Use the node name as an agent on pipeline script to do NPM build step and other steps accordingly.

For designing pipeline please check:
https://github.com/darinpope/jenkins-example-parallel

Let me know if that solves the issue you are facing.

Comment: How can I integrate Jenkins with AWS server, i don't have admin access for Jenkins

Comment: Jenkins is an application and it will need installation on a machine which can access AWS server. 
Easiest will be if both are on AWS as per. @Luuk

OR 
From AWS Documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/setting-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-by-integrating-jenkins-with-aws-codebuild-and-aws-codedeploy/
If you dont have admin access then please ignore my suggestion.

If you want to explore more options then jenkins documentation will be helpful:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/